# List shuffling with shuffleM

Tags: haskell

I try to write a function that takes a list and give permutation of it. In ghci I can do something like this:

```
>let xs=[1..10]
>ys <- shuffleM xs
```

both xs and ys have the type [Integer] and ys is indeed a permutation of xs. I want to get the same effect in a programme, because after shuffling I need to use ys further. How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let xs = [1..10]
    ys <- shuffleM xs
    print $ doSomething ys

doSomething :: [Integer] -> Integer
doSomething = sum
```

For example.  I'm not sure where `shuffleM` comes from, but if it's from the [random-shuffle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-shuffle-0.0.3/docs/System-Random-Shuffle.html) library then you just have to use it inside a monad that implements `MonadRandom`, which includes `IO`.  Then you can process the shuffled list just like you would any other list.